# How to write xpath for the text enclosed in the <br> tags?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, chropath

I am trying to write xpath for the text inside the 'br' tags for the below html code. When I tried to highlight the xpath through 'chropath'(plugin for chrome), it shows '0 elements matching'. Please help me resolving this.

```
<div class="abc" style="">Line1. 
<br>Line2: 
<br>Line3
<br>Line4
<br>
<br> Line5
</div>
```

xpath that I tried

```
//div[contains(text(),'Line1')]/text()[following-sibling::node()[1][self::br]]
```

Comment: Your question is unclear - are you interested in the text after each `<br>` tag (that is, all text except `Line1`? And does that text always contain the string `Line`?

Comment: Which language bindings are you using Java/Python/C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't get text from `<br/>` tag, it's line breaks. So in your case, you can use the `xpath` : `//*[@class='abc']` for get all text. But if you want get text each line, may this is need to try :

```
WebElement elemnt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='abc']"));

String lines[] = elemnt.getText().split("\\r?\\n");
for(String line: lines) {
    System.out.println("line :" +line);
}
```

Implement in `java`.

Output console :

[image: console]

Answer (score 0):

`<br/>` tags are used to define line breaks. So the text is not inside a `<br/>` tag.

To answer your questions, If you specifically want to get the text followed by  a `<br/>` tag, you can use a reference number to it. For Example
`(//div[contains(text(),'Line1')]/text())[2]` Here, the `[2]` will refer to the text **Line 2** and so on.